# FastAPI Integrity Error - Null Value or relation not-null constraint

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Once I did all changes to convert the example  SQL (Relational) Databases (`https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/`)
in `Async model` I am able to create user however for item I get the error:

```
raise translated_error from error
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError'>: null value in column "owner_id" of relation "items" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, string, string, null).
[SQL: INSERT INTO items (title, description, owner_id) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::INTEGER) RETURNING items.id]
[parameters: ('string', 'string', None)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
```

After investigate and do some test such manually inser `owner_id` I realized that model is raise that error.

here are my files:

`database.py`

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    metadata = MetaData(naming_convention={
        "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
        "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
        "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
        "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
        "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s",
    })

load_dotenv()

engine = create_async_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

`schemas`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ItemBase(BaseModel):
  title: str
  description: str | None = None


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
  pass


class Item(ItemBase):
  id: int
  owner_id: int

  class Config:
    from_attributes = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
  username: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
  password: str
  email: str


class User(UserBase):
  id: int
  is_active: bool
  items: list[Item] = []

  class Config:
    from_attributes = True
```

`models`

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as so

from database import Base


class Item(Base):
  __tablename__ = "items"

  id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
  title: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String, index=True)
  description: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.Text, index=True)
  owner_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(
        sa.ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)

  user: so.Mapped['User'] = so.relationship(
     lazy='joined',
     innerjoin=True,
     back_populates='items'
    )

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Item({self.id} "{self.title}")'


class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = "users"

  id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
  username: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String, unique=True, index=True)
  email: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String, unique=True, index=True)
  hashed_password: so.Mapped[str]
  is_active: so.Mapped[bool] = so.mapped_column(sa.Boolean, default=True)

  items: so.Mapped[list['Item']] = so.relationship(
      lazy='selectin',
      cascade='all, delete-orphan',
      back_populates='user'
    )

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'User({self.id})'
```

`main.py`

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import select, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession


import crud, models, schemas
from database import SessionLocal


app = FastAPI()


async def get_db():
  db = SessionLocal()
  try:
    yield db
  finally:
    await db.close()


@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
async def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
   fake_hashed_password = user.password + "notreallyhashed"
   db_user = models.User(
     username = user.username,
     email = user.email,
     hashed_password = fake_hashed_password
    )
   db.add(db_user)
   await db.commit()
   # await db.refresh(db_user)
   return db_user


@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item)
async def create_item_for_user(
   user_id: int,
   item: schemas.ItemCreate,
   db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
   ):
  #  db_item = models.Item(**item.model_dump(), owner_id=1)
  db_item = models.Item(
     title = item.title,
     description = item.description,
     owner_id = user_id)
  db.add(db_item)
  await db.commit()
  await db.refresh(db_item)
  return db_item
```

I am not able to read user created, I guess it is because this relationship with an issue, please your expertise is appreciate.
thanks

Comment: `user_id` is not `None` because user input in  `@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/"...)`  route. However when db.commit() is send to DB, error above in question returning indicating that owner_id is None or a relation constraint error

Comment: Actually `schemas,ItemCreate` allow to have in `body` owner_id however it is required in `Path`already and even trying result is same `(title, description, owner_id) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::INTEGER) RETURNING items.id]
[parameters: ('title01', 'to do', None)]`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create the `item` for `user_id` in 3 steps after validations for `user` and `item`:

1. Query user from User.mode `user = db.get(models.User,user_id)`
2. Append `db_item = models.Item(**item.model_dump())` to `user.item.append(db_item)`
3. Finally add `db_item` and commit it